# How to create simple counter using Beanshell?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

I'm trying to create a simple counter that will print the iteration number to the log.
the problem is that I didn't find a way to initialize the int value of i to 0.
if I'll do it inside the Beanshell script it will keep initializing, I need it to run only once at the beginning of the test.
My code:

```
int i=0;
log.info(string.valueOf(i));
i=i+1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Once Only Controller, under it JSR223 Sampler with the initialization

```
vars.putObject("i", 0);
```

Then you can increment it after it (not under the Controller) with other JSR223 Sampler:

```
myI = vars.getObject("i")
log.info(String.valueOf(myI));
vars.putObject("i", ((Integer)myI+1));
```

Comment: I'm getting errors. which language should I choose under the JSR223 sampler?

Comment: ok it works now. I added user defined variable "i" under test plan, then changed lang to Groovy. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to avoid scripting where possible, and if you cannot live without scripting you should be using the most performing option which is [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language.

Particularly your case can be implemented without any scripting, you can use the following JMeter Functions:

- [__log()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__log) - which prints an arbitrary message to *jmeter.log* file
- [__iterationNum()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup) - which returns the number of current iteration

So if you use the statement like: `${__log(Current iteration is: ${__iterationNum},,,)}` JMeter will return it where the function is called and additionally print the corresponding message to the log file.

Demo:

[image: JMeter IterationNum Function Demo]

You can install **__iterationNum()** function as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Custom Functions Plugins Manager]